# How to install Sentellic fspc package?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I installed a package from Sentellic, called fspc but seems I can't install it due some dependencies, how to correctly install it?

Comment: Doesn't running `apt-get -f install` and then trying to reinstall the package works?

Comment: This is what I got when I ran apt-get -f install:
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 libwxgtk2.8-0: 2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2 (Multi-Arch: same) is not co-installable with libwxgtk2.8-0:i386 2.8.10.1-0ubuntu1 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Aditya he mentions that running that didn't work.

Comment: closers, please read: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7955/to-the-closers-of-377087-which-has-an-excellent-answer

Comment: @Braiam: please refer my answer on the linked meta question for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the offending package:

```
sudo dpkg --remove fspc libwxgtk2.8-0:i386
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now install it like pro's do, using `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi /path/to/fscp.deb
```

Comment: The problem is that whenever I try to use apt-get, I get the same message in my post above.

Comment: @user215833 updated my answer.